# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it LARAVEL 4 error

Tags: php, redis, laravel

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379] in laravel 4.

My code is:

```php
$redis = Redis::connection();
$redis->set('name', 'Taylor');
$name = $redis->get('name');
$values = $redis->lrange('names', 5, 10);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you've got redis set up correctly, and you're targeting the correct port?

Answer (score 8):

After Installing redis server(you can download it form [redis](https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads)) you should simply run file `redis-server.exe` often located in `C:\Program Files\Redis\`
and refresh your page!

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: `redis-server.exe` will handle all requests to redis server. therefore it should be run.

Comment: @VahidMontazer In windows environment, how to fork the process, or how to start the service in the boot time like apache and other services?

Comment: @jthedev Do you mean when windows or apache starts, redis also starts? If yes, I don't know certain answer, but my redis server (redis-server.exe) is started always when windows starts. I can see it in task manager -> proccess list.

Comment: @VahidMontazer: Thank you Vahid, the service was there in the windows services list. I changed the settings to start it automatically. Now it is starting in the boot time itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that your redis instance either isn't running at all or is running on different host and/or port address (or port 6379 is closed by firewall).

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error below:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Because I didn't start **RabbitMQ** so after starting **RabbitMQ**, the error was solved.

So, your case with **Redis** will be the same. You should start **Redis** to solve the error.